# Is there anyway to use value stored in variable as a key for searching another variable of a Class?

Tags: python, class, variables, jenkins

Currently I am working on a selenium project which I am integrated with Jenkins.I have stored Locators in a class. So my target is to take input from jenkins and use that variable as a key to get value from the

```
class Locators(object):
    rundate = 'PREV' # This value is user input, either PREV or NOW
    PREV = 'abcd'
    NOW  = 'bcd'
```

So I want to use it as:

`Test = Locators()
Test.(Test.rundate)`

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dotted attribute access always requires a valid identifier for the attribute name, not an arbitrary expression. Use `getattr` in other situations.

```
getattr(Test, Test.rundate)
```